# Contour Integral question with respect to given curve

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm asked to find $$\int_{\gamma}e^{2z} \left(\frac{1}{(z+4)}+\frac {1}{(z-2)^2}\right)dz$$ with respect to the following contour:

[image: Contour Integral]

Does this mean that the index of $\gamma$, which is $I(\gamma,z_i)=1$? Or do I have to discuss any estimates needed to justify my answer? I end up with: $$\int_{\gamma}e^{2z} \left(\frac{1}{(z+4)}+\frac {1}{(z-2)^2}\right)dz=2\pi i(Res(f,2)+Res(f,-4))=2\pi i(2e^4+e^{-8})$$

Comment: The winding number about the two singularities is not the same.

Comment: You can shrink your contour to being a clockwise contour around $-4$ (so the winding number is $-1$) and a counterclockwise contour around $2$ (so the winding number is $1$).

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm using a formula on my book. Not sure if I have it correct the calculation is really messy. What are you getting for $Res(f,2)$?

Comment: @CameronWilliams I didn't know winding numbers can be negative. Nothing was ever said about winding numbers being negative during my intro to complex class lecture but I can see why it would be negative since we're going clockwise here. Thanks for the tip I'll be doing more research on that.

Comment: For the residue of $\dfrac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^2}$ in $z_0$, write $f(z) = f(z_0) + f'(z_0)(z-z_0) + g(z)(z-z_0)^2$ to see that the residue is $f'(z_0)$. - Oh, it seems I have overlooked the factor $2$ previously and your residue _is_ correct. Sorry for the noise. But the winding number issue is correct, overall, you get $2\pi i(2e^4 - e^{-8})$ then.

Comment: @DanielFischer whewww took me hours to figure that residue out correctly. And I like the way you did it it's much easier than using the formula I had.

Comment: What formula had you?

Comment: First I added the two rational expressions inside the parenthesis so that I have a function that looks like $\frac{g(z)}{h(z)}$, then I apply a type of criterion that I must do in order to apply the formula. If $g(z_0)\neq 0$, $h(z_0)=0=h'(z_0)$, $h''(z_0) \neq0$ then $$Res(f,z_0)=2\frac{g'(z_0)}{h''(z_0)}-\frac{2}{3} \frac{g(z_0)h'''(z_0)}{[h''(z_0)]^2}$$